# Function $y(x)$ fulfill $y'(x)=y(x)$. Also $y(0)<0$. Proof that $y(x)<0$ for every $x$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Function $y(x)$ fulfills $y'(x)=y(x)$. Also $y(0)<0$. Proof that $y(x)<0$ for every $x$.

Can someone help me with this one. I have some ideas:

1. Let $x_0$  be the smallest such that $y(x_0) \geq 0$ (if exist). So $y$ increase. From  $0$ to $x_0$ derivative of $y$ is negative so $y$ decrease. Thus $y(x_0)<y(0)$, but $y(0) < 0$. So $y(x_0)<0$.
2. Let $x_0<0$ be the highest such that $y(x_0) \geq 0.$ If $y(x_0)>0$ then $y'(x_0)>0$. So $y(x_0+\alpha)\geq 0$ for small enough $\alpha$. But we have that $y(0)<0$. So $y(x_0)$ have to be eqaul to $0$.

So there is last case and i think the hardest one where $y(x_0)=0$.

Can someone explain me what to do next.

Btw sorry for my english.

Comment: Consider $(e^{-x}y(x))'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$y'(x)=y(x)$$
$$y'-y=0$$
Use integrating factor $\mu (x) =e^{-x}$:
$$(ye^{-x})'=0$$
$$y(x)=Ce^{x}$$
Since $y(0)<0 \implies C<0$ so that $y(x)<0 \, \forall \, x$.